# Regularity of the mild solution of a semilinear evolution equation

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, operator-theory, semigroups-of-operators

Let

- $T>0$
- $H$ be a separable $\mathbb R$-Hilbert space
- $u_0\in H$
- $(e_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq\mathcal D(A)$ be an orthonormal basis of $H$ with $$Ae_n=\lambda_ne_n\;\;\;\text{for all }n\in\mathbb N$$ for some $(\lambda_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq(0,\infty)$ with $$\lambda_{n+1}\ge\lambda_n\;\;\;\text{for all }n\in\mathbb N$$
- $S(t):=e^{-tA}$ with $$e^{-tA}x:=\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}e^{-t\lambda_n}\langle x,e_n\rangle_He_n\;\;\;\text{for }x\in H$$ for $t\ge 0$
- $f:H\to H$ with $$\left\|f(x)\right\|_H\le L(1+\left\|x\right\|_H)\;\;\;\text{for all }x\in H\tag1$$ and $$\left\|f(x)-f(y)\right\|_H\le L\left\|x-y\right\|_H\;\;\;\text{for all }x,y\in H\tag2$$

Note that $S$ is a $C^0$-semigroup on $H$ and $-A$ is the infinitesimal generator of $S$.

> It's well known that there is a unique $u\in C^0([0,T],H)$ with $$u(t)=S(t)u_0+\underbrace{\int_0^tS(t-s)f(u(s))\:{\rm d}s}_{=:\:v(t)}\;\;\;\text{for all }t\in[0,T]\tag 3\;.$$

Let $t\in (0,T)$ and $h\in[0,T-t)$. Then, $$\frac{v(t+h)-v(t)}h=\frac{S(h)-\operatorname{id}_H}hv(t)+\underbrace{\frac1h\int_t^{t+h}S(t+h-s)f(u(s))\:{\rm d}s}_{=:\:I_h(t)}\tag 4$$ with $$I_{\tilde h}(t)\xrightarrow{\tilde h\to0}f(u(t))\tag 5\;.$$

> **Question**: What can we say about the regularity of $v$? Is $v$ (continuously) differentiable? And if so, in which sense is it a solution of $$\frac{{\rm d}v}{{\rm d}t}(\tilde t)=-Av(\tilde t)+f(u(\tilde t))\tag 6$$ for all $\tilde t\in[0,T]$?

The question arose as I read [page 111](https://books.google.de/books?id=GX_RAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA111&lpg=PA111&dq=%22Using+the+definition+of+mild+solution%22+%22Similarly,+by+differentiating+the+variation%22&source=bl&ots=ailB9dOXlf&sig=lPbYXWfX6tF9X9BnrDedZCsg5hY&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwipjcaB3JzRAhXMB8AKHc8iDegQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=%22Using%20the%20definition%20of%20mild%20solution%22%20%22Similarly%2C%20by%20differentiating%20the%20variation%22&f=false) of *An Introduction to Computational Stochastic PDEs*. The authors claim that $u$ is not "smooth enough to interpret $(6)$ directly, as we don't know whether $u(t)\in\mathcal D(A)$".

Now, $$\frac{S(h)-\operatorname{id}_H}hv(t)=\int_0^t\frac{S(h)-\operatorname{id}_H}hS(t-s)f(u(s))\:{\rm d}s\tag 7$$ and (since $S(t-s)f(u(s))\in\mathcal D(A)$ for all $s\in[0,t)$) $$\frac{S(\tilde h)-\operatorname{id}_H}{\tilde h}S(t-s)f(u(s))\xrightarrow{\tilde h\to0}-AS(t-s)f(u(s))\;\;\;\text{for all }s\in[0,t)\tag 8\;.$$ Since the convergence in $(8)$ is uniformly with respect to $s$ and $t$, the right-hand side of $(7)$ is convergent as $h\to0+$. Thus, the left-hand side of $(7)$ is convergent as $h\to0+$ and hence $v(t)\in\mathcal D(A)$ by the very definition of $\mathcal D(A)$.

> So, we should be able to conclude $u(t)\in\mathcal D(A)$. Did I made any mistake or are the authors wrong?

Comment: Your (7) looks suspicious to me.

Comment: @FanZheng $S(h)-\text{id}_H$ is a bounded linear operator on $H$ and it's easy to see that $$[0,t]\ni s\mapsto S(t-s)f(u(s))\tag 9$$ is integrable over $[0,t]$. It's well-known that $(7)$ holds in this situation.

Comment: Maybe there is an other problem: Denote the function $(9)$ by $g$. We have the estimate $$\left\|Ag(s)\right\|\le\frac C{t-s}\;\;\;\text{for all }s\in[0,t)\tag{10}$$ for some $C\ge 0$. However, $$\int_0^t\frac1{(t-s)^\alpha}\:{\rm d}s$$ won't exist, unless $\alpha<1$. So, if there is no stronger estimate than $(10)$, $$\int_0^tAg(s)\:{\rm d}s$$ might be undefined. However, in that case the book would be heavily wrong and that's why I guess that I'm missing something.

Comment: I guess you are missing some terms as when f=0 the RHS is 0 but the RHS is not.

Comment: @FanZheng You've written "RHS" twice and I don't know which equation you're talking about. If you mean $(7)$, then $v\equiv 0$ in the case $f\equiv 0$. Hence, both sides of $(7)$ are $0$ in that case. (Maybe you've confused $u$ with $v$.)

Comment: Yes, your u and v is very confusing. v seems to appear in(4) without any definition.

Comment: @FanZheng $v$ is defined in $(3)$; $$v(t)\stackrel{\text{def}}=\int_0^tS(t-s)f(u(s))\:{\rm d}s\;\;\;\text{for }t\in[0,T]\;.$$

Comment: Sorry about that. The under brace jumped off screen on my phone.

Comment: @FanZheng No problem; that happens sometimes in the mobile version.

Comment: If $S$ is a uniformly continuous semigroup, then isn't $D(A)=H$? So what is there to prove? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @MichaelRenardy Did you take a look at the book? In their scenario, we have an orthonormal basis $(e_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}⊆\mathcal D(A)$ of $H$ with $$Ae_n=\lambda_ne_n\;\;\;\text{for all }n\in\mathbb N\tag{11}$$ for some $(\lambda_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}⊆(0,\infty)$ with $$\lambda_{n+1}\ge\lambda_n\;\;\;\text{for all }n\in\mathbb N\tag{12}\;.$$ Now they define $$e^{-tA}x:=\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}e^{-\lambda_nt}\langle x,e_n\rangle_He_n\;\;\;\text{for }t\ge 0\text{ and }x\in H$$ and $$S(t):=e^{-tA}\;\;\;\text{for }t\ge0\;.$$ This $S$ should be a uniformly continuous semigroup; but $\mathcal D(A)\ne H$.

Comment: @0xbadf00d: No, this semigroup is NOT uniformly continuous. Uniform continuity fails at t=0!

Comment: @MichaelRenardy However, I wrote the question with this particular $S$ in mind. I thought it would be an unnecessary detail and that's why I didn't wrote down its particular shape. Just in case, I've added this detail to the question. (And you're right, $S$ is just a $C^0$-semigroup. I've mistakenly concluded the uniform continuity from Lemma 3.22.)

Comment: I think you use that $-A$ is the generator of an analytic (!) semigroup (for instance when you argue that $S(t-s)f(u(s)) \in D(A)$ for $s \in [0,t)$, but also when---probably--- you want to infer that $S(t)u_0 \in D(A)$ for $t > 0$). I am also inclined to think that the phrasing in the book is just not very precise - what is "interpret (equation) directly" supposed to mean, anyway? Note that you cannot have $u$ (right) differentiable in $0$ with values in $D(A)$ due to $u_0$ not being from $D(A)$, which could maybe be the point the authors want to make?

Comment: @Hannes (a) We have $$S(t)x∈\mathcal D(A^α)\;\;\;\text{for all }α≥0,t>0\text{ and }x∈ H\tag{13}\;.$$ This is an easy consequence of $$S(t)x∈\mathcal D(A^α)\Leftrightarrow\sum_{n∈\mathbb N}λ_n^{2α}\left|e^{-λ_nt}\langle x,e_n\rangle_H\right|^2<\infty\tag{14}\;\;\;\text{for all }α∈\mathbb R,t≥0\text{ and }x∈ H$$ and $$θ^α e^{-θ}\le\left(\fracα e\right)^α\;\;\;\text{for all }α>0\text{ and }θ≥0\tag{15}\;.$$ (b) I think their point is that $u(t)\not∈\mathcal D(A)$ and hence the expression $Au(t)$ is not well-defined for any $t∈[0,T]$. Their proof of $u(t)\in\mathcal D(A^{1/2})$ even shows that

Comment: @Hannes $u(t)\in\mathcal D(A^α)$ for all $α<1$ and $t>0$. $(c)$ They confuse me with their statement that $\frac{{\rm d}u}{{\rm d}t}(t)\in\mathcal D(A^{-1/2})$ for all $t>0$. First of all, they state that $$\frac{{\rm d}u}{{\rm d}t}(t)=-AS(t)u_0-\int_0^tAS(t-s)f(u(s))\:{\rm d}s+f(u(t))\;\;\;\text{for all }t≥0\tag{16}\;.$$ I don't see why this is true. Let $$g(s):=S(t-s)f(u(s))\;\;\;\text{for }s∈[0,t]\;.$$ Then it's clear that $$g(s)\in\mathcal D(A)\tag{17}$$ and hence $$\frac{S(h)-\text{id}_H}hg(s)\xrightarrow{h\to0+}-Ag(s)\tag{18}$$ for all $s∈[0,t)$.

Comment: @Hannes From $(16)$ it seems like they are concluding $$\int_0^t\frac{S(h)-\text{id}_H}hg(s)\:{\rm d}s\xrightarrow{h\to0+}-\int_0^tAg(s)\:{\rm d}s\;.\tag{19}$$ from $(18)$; but I don't see why we can do that. Moreover, if $(16)$ is really true, shouldn't we have  $\frac{{\rm d}u}{{\rm d}t}(t)\in H$ for all $t∈[0,T]$? But [since $H\subseteq\mathcal D(A^α)$ for all $α\le0$](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/2079788/47771), their statement $\frac{{\rm d}u}{{\rm d}t}(t)\in\mathcal D(A^{-1/2})$ would be trivial.

Comment: @0xbadf00d Theorem 3.1 + Theorem 3.3 in Chapter 6 in [Pazy's book](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-1-4612-5561-1) says that, under the assumptions in the chapter of the book you linked, there is a unique classical solution of the semilinear equation $u'(t) = Au(t) + f(u(t))$ with $u(0) = u_0 \in H$, which means that $u \in C([0,T];H) \cap C^1((0,T];H)$ and $u(t) \in D(A)$ for all $t \in (0,T)$. I guess that since the authors in your book are aiming for a weak formulation for the Galerkin ansatz anyway, they did not bother with classical solutions ("lemma does not provide..")?

Comment: @Hannes (a) I think it's pretty clear that they claim that their mild solution $u$, whose existence is proved in Theorem 3.29, doesn't satisfy $u(t)\in\mathcal D(A)$ for any $t\in(0,T]$; but only $u(t)\in\mathcal D(A^{1/2})$ for all $t\in(0,T]$. As I said before, the same argument as they use could be used to show even $u(t)\in\mathcal D(A^\alpha)$ for all $\alpha<1$ and $t\in(0,T]$. This last thing are they doing, cause they explicitly need  $u(t)\in\mathcal D(A^{1/2})$ for all $t\in(0,T]$ to motivate the notion of a weak solution.

Comment: @Hannes (b) The theorems you've mentioned are assuming that $u_0\in\mathcal D(A^\alpha)$ for some $\alpha\in(0,1)$. Actually, $\alpha$ isn't defined in Theorem 3.3, but I guess that this $\alpha$ should be the same as in Theorem 3.1. However, is that the crucial point? In the book in the question, they assume $u_0\in H$. (c) What do you say to the problem I've mentioned in my previous comments? Can $(19)$ be concluded?

Comment: My version of Pazy seems not to require $\alpha \in (0,1)$..

Comment: @Hannes In Theorem 3.1 of my version, he states: "If $0<\alpha<1$ and $f$ satisfies the assumption $(F)$ ...". Here is a [link](http://tinyurl.com/zlwhsmt) to the Google Books version. And, as I said before, he doesn't write what $\alpha$ is in Theorem 3.3. But since he uses Theorem 3.1 to obtain the existence of a local mild solution (which then is shown to be extendable) in the proof of Theorem 3.3, it should be clear that $\alpha$ needs to satisfy the assumptions needed to apply Theorem 3.1. What do you say to (c)?

Comment: Yeah sorry, I had the first edition of Pazy at hand and there is no such requirement on $\alpha$. Embarassing.

Comment: @Hannes There are two open problems here: When they write $\frac{{\rm d}u}{{\rm d}t}$, do they mean the classical derivative of $u$ (which would require $u\in C^1((0,T),H)$, or the weak derivative? From their representation of $\frac{{\rm d}u}{{\rm d}t}$, it seems like they mean the classical derivative (which is confusing, since they write $u\in C^0([0,T],H)$). And this leads me to $(c)$ again, since this might be the reason why their representation is wrong. So, let me ask again, do you think that $(c)$ can be concluded from $(16)$? Is there any argument I'm missing?

Comment: @0xbadf00d So: Since $T$ is analytic, the initial value $u_0 \in H$ poses no problem when going for classical solutions (Cor. 4.1.5 in Pazy). The regularity of $v$ is independent of $u_0$, and I think it is correct that $v(t) \in D(A)$ for every $t > 0$. However, it is not clear why $t \mapsto Av(t)$ should be continuous since $f(u(t))$ is not guaranteed to lie in $D(A)$ (see Thm. 4.2.4 and Cor. 4.2.6 in Pazy). This should be the point where it fails to interpret (3.54) in your book classically. Sorry for the confusion before.

Comment: @Hannes I will take a look at what you wrote soon; but you repeatedly avoided to reply to my question (c). I'm really interested in what you think about my concerns, since I don't see why their formula for $\frac{{\rm d}u}{{\rm d}t}$ should hold without that conclusion.

Comment: @0xbadf00d well I've been trying to answer your original question so far, no? :-) (16) just looks like the result of the Leibniz rule for me, done formally to get an idea what the derivative HAS to look like if it exists in whatever sense (then one can make sense of it in a weak or distributional way).

Comment: @Hannes Yes, you've tried to answer the original question and I thank your for that. (I've still didn't looked at what you wrote; but I will soon). Let me ask my question in the most precise way: Can we conclude $(19)$ from $(18)$? That would be the case, for example, if we the convergence in $(18)$ is uniform; but I have no argument for that. Another option would be an application of the dominated convergence theorem; but here the problem I've mentioned below $(10)$ should prevent an application (there is no dominating integrable function).

Comment: @Hannes Now I've read what you wrote: (a) Corollary 4.1.5 (on page 104 in my Version) adresses the Cauchy Problem. So, I don't see how you intend to use it here. (b) $v(t)\in\mathcal D(A)$ for all $t\in(0,T]$ is the crucial point and it holds if and only if $(19)$ holds. That's why I've repeatedly asked you whether you see that $(19)$ is implied by $(18)$. $(c)$ We don't need $f(u(t))\in\mathcal D(A)$ for any $t\in[0,T]$. All we need is $(19)$.

Answer (score 1):

As I don't know exactly what you would like to ask on $A$, the answer I give can only be very vague and not much better than the comments given by Hannes.  It would be good if you could  specify your question (e.g. do you mean regularity in space or in time?)  and give a link to the version of the book you are referring to?

In my version of the book you refer to, Lemma 3.35 on page 111 tells you that $u(t) \in \mathcal{D}(A^{1/2})$. You can see why by just going through the proof of Lemma 3.22. on page 102, where the regularity of solutions is derived via the properties of the semigroup.

As already indicated by Hannes, without further assumption we cannot prove that $u(t) \in \mathcal{D}(A)$, as this would require the finiteness of $\| A u(t) \|$ instead of  $\| A^{1/2} u(t) \| < \infty$, as shown in Lemma 3.35. The condition  $\| A u(t) \| < \infty$ is true e.g. in the case of a fast enough growth of the eigenvalues of A (which depends also on the dimension of the open set $D$).

Taking for example the $A= \Delta$ with Dirichlet boundary conditions, the domain of $A$  is $\mathcal{D}(A) = H^2 \cap H^1_0$, as pointed out also in Example 3.24.

Now I get even more vague in w.r.t. answering your original question: How regular a solution to a semilinear (S)PDE  is depends on the operator $A$ and how much $A$ "smoothes" the initial data over time. Also, as you pointed out already, the type of solution that one is looking for makes a difference in the results one can get. So there is no quick and general answer to this question.  If you are looking for regularity results on second order operators, best is probably to check Gilbarg-Trudinger. Showalter has results in case that $A$ is a monotone operator.

The problem is also that the chapter of this book has just merely informative character, it just states a couple of background results from the deterministic setting needed in later chapters (when we do have a noise term). So it does not aim in being concise. The setup given is also aligned to the setup one classically uses in SPDE theory, where you will see that the condition  $\| A u(t) \| < \infty$ appears in the definition of so-called "strong solutions" to SPDEs.

Comment: There are two questions: (a) I claim that $u(t)\in\mathcal D(A^α)$ for all $α<1$ by the same argument as in the book. Can we show more?

Comment: (b) What can we say about $\frac{{\rm d}u}{{\rm d}t}$? The book states $\frac{{\rm d}u}{{\rm d}t}∈\mathcal D(A^{-1/2})$ which doesn't make much sense, since $\mathcal D(A^β)=H$ for all $β≤0$; if I'm not terribly wrong. Moreover, the book states that $\frac{{\rm d}u}{{\rm d}t}$ satisfies $(16)$ (from the comments below the question), which should imply $\frac{{\rm d}u}{{\rm d}t}\in H$. And I'm curious whether $(19)$ can be concluded from $(18)$, since I see no other way to obtain $(16)$.

Answer (score 0):

This problem has been addressed by many authors. Here I present a general result (Theorem 4.1) from the "Abstract parabolic equations and their applications" by A. Yagi. 
Let us consider the following semilinear equation in $X$:
\begin{equation}
\left\{\begin{array}{l}
u'(t)+Au(t)=F(u)+g(t), t>0\\
u(0)=u_0,
\end{array}\right.
\end{equation}
where $F:D(A^\eta)\to X$, ($0<\eta< 1$) satisfies 
$$
\|F(u)-F(v)\|\leq \varphi(\|A^\beta u\|+\|A^\beta v\|)\|A^\eta(u-v)\|+(\|A^\eta u\|+\|A^\eta u\|)(\|A^\beta (u-v)\|)\quad \forall~u,v\in D(A^\eta).
$$
with some $0<\beta \leq \eta<1$. Then we have the following result:
Given any $g\in \mathcal{F}^{\beta,\sigma}((0,T];D(A^\beta))$, where $0<\sigma<1-\eta$, and any $u_0\in D(A^\beta)$. The equation above possesses a unique local solution $U$ in the function space:
$$
u\in C((0,T_{g,u_0}];D(A))\cap C([0,T_{g,u_0}];D(A^\beta))\cap C^{1}((0,T_{g,u_0}];X),
$$
and 
$$
\frac{d u}{dt},~Au\in \mathcal{F}^{\beta,\sigma}((0,T];X),
$$
where $T_{g,u_0}$ depends only on the norms of $g$ and $A^\beta u_0$. You can apply this result directly. Below is the definition of the function space used here. (It is midnight in Hong Kong, and I really need to sleep. This is just a draft. Sorry to use the picture instead of typing myself. If I have time, then I may update more).

[image]

[image]

Comment: The problem is that your theorem requires $u_0\in\mathcal D(A^\beta)$ for some $\beta\in(0,1)$; but we only know that $u_0\in H$. Moreover, you say that I can imply this result directly, but it only gives me a *local* solution, while I'm searching for a global one.